# Bottle: execute a long running function asynchronously and send an early response to the client?

Tags: python, rest, python-2.7, asynchronous, bottle

The Bottle app (behind CherryPy) that I'm working on receives a request for a resource from an HTTP client which results in an execution of a task that can take a few hours to finish. I'd like to send an early HTTP response (e.g., `202 Accepted`) and continue processing the task. Is there a way to achieve this without using MQ libraries and using Python/Bottle alone?

For example:

```
from bottle import HTTPResponse

@route('/task')
def f():
    longRunningTask() # <-- Anyway to make this asynchronous? 
    return bottle.HTTPResponse(status=202)
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is several years old but I found @ahmed's answer so unbelievably unhelpful that I thought I would at least share how I solved this problem in my application.

All I did was make use of Python's existing threading libraries, as below:

```py
from bottle import HTTPResponse
from threading import Thread

@route('/task')
def f():
    task_thread = Thread(target=longRunningTask) # create a thread that will execute your longRunningTask() function
    task_thread.setDaemon(True) # setDaemon to True so it terminates when the function returns
    task_thread.start() # launch the thread
    return bottle.HTTPResponse(status=202)
```

Using threads allows you to maintain a consistent response time while still having relatively complex or time-consuming functions.

I used uWSGI, so do make sure you enable threading in your uWSGI application config if that's the way you went.